# How to successfully verify that 2 names are identical?

Tags: python, e-commerce

I have order validation in place, where I validate that the account name matches billing name.

Currently I'm looking for 100% match.
There are many case where this validation fails as the 2 names are slightly different.

how do you recommend me doing such thing in Python?

I was thinking of checking if the account name first name is part of the billing address and the same goes for last name.

Or maybe check only first X characters of the first name and the last name.

What is the best practice out there?

Thanks

Comment: My advice is to stop doing this. It can't be done correctly in 100% cases and annoying your customers is not the best way to get them buying from your store.

Comment: I want to screen third party payments so dropping this validation is not an option.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do this in the first place? It's not clear to me what security it provides. If Alice Badguy steals Bob Everyman's credit card, then when she buys from your store, she's going to make an account with the name "Bob Everyman" and it will happily let her through.

Comment: You're right, this is not 100% bullet proof, but I'm also validating many other parameters that all must pass before I label the order as legit.

What are your best practices?

Comment: In general, this can't be done.  If you think it can, read Patrick McKenzie's "[Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)", and think again.  That's 40 problems for you to solve, just to get started.  Here's #41:  ask the business owner what percent of legitimate customers --- who have already ordered and are _engaged in the act of paying him_ --- he's willing to turn away because his Web site says their name isn't good enough.  Actually, make that question #0, and get it in writing _before_ you start coding.

Comment: so you basically say to allow any character for name and drop the name validation?

Comment: I don't see how this check adds any value. If you want the names to be the same then ask only the account name and use that as billing name as well. That way your users have one less field to fill out and you guarantee the names are always the same.

Comment: I receive the billing info from PayPal.
anyway, i will drop this validation as it makes too much trouble for my customers and doesn't add any benefit at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try for any existing fuzzy string matching algorithm in Python.

E.g. SimString

http://www.chokkan.org/software/simstring/

Hope it will help.